# SQLALCHEMY can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base.NUMBER'>

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to copy a table from one oracle database to postgre database using sqlalchemy
After setting up connection and engine in oracle and postgre and reflecting tables to the sourceMeta metadata, I try to create in the destEngine, but it gives me an error saying cant render element of type...

```
for t in sourceMeta.sorted_tables:
    newtable = Table(t.name, sourceMeta, autoload=True)
    newtable.metadata.create_all(destEngine)
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems what you are looking for is sqlalchemys @compiles decorator. 
Here is an example of how it worked for me when trying to copy tables from a MS SQL Server db to a PostgreSQL db.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import TINYINT, DATETIME, VARCHAR

@compiles(TINYINT, 'postgresql')
def compile_TINYINT_mssql_int(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ Handles mssql TINYINT datatype as INT in postgresql """
    return 'INTEGER'
# add a function for each datatype that causes an error

table_name = '<table_name>'

# create engine, reflect existing columns, and create table object for oldTable
srcEngine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<db>')
srcEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=srcEngine)
srcEngine._metadata.reflect(srcEngine)  # get columns from existing table
srcTable = Table(table_name, srcEngine._metadata)

# create engine and table object for newTable
destEngine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<password>@<host><db>')
destEngine._metadata = MetaData(bind=destEngine)
destTable = Table(table_name.lower(), destEngine._metadata)

# copy schema and create newTable from oldTable
for column in srcTable.columns:
    dstCol = column.copy()
    destTable.append_column(dstCol)
    # maybe change column name etc.
print(CreateTable(destTable).compile(destEngine))  # <- check the query that will be used to create the table
destTable.create()
```

check the docs:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/compiler.html
and maybe also this example:
https://gist.github.com/methane/2972461